# Extract all parent and child nodes from xml

Tags: python, linux, xml

I've a very large nested XML file (below is an minimalist example) and I'm trying to understand what are all the parent and child nodes.

Currently, I load this xml file to beautifulsoup in python and read each node individually. The problem I see is that I do not how many parent nodes are there and what they are.

What is the quickest way to find the set of parent nodes and the corresponding child nodes?

```
<AppTestData>
    <Contact>
        <Name>
         <First name> foo</First name>
         <last name> bar</last name>
        </Name>
        <Age>33</Age>
        <City>York</City>
        ...
    </Contact>
    <Agent>
        <Code>A103S</Code>
        <Region>North</North>
        <Resp>Service</Resp>
        ....
    </Agent>
    <Product>
        <Cat>Electronics</Cat>
        ...
    </Product> 
</AppTestData>
```

Hopeful output:

```
AppTestData -> Contact -> [Name, age, city]
AppTestData -> Contact -> Name ->[first name, last name]
AppTestData -> Agent -> [Code, Region, Resp]
```

Comment: The child nodes of <Name>, like `<First name>` have a space in the node name; can you recheck and edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one. I've modified the error in your XML.

```
from simplified_scrapy import  utils, SimplifiedDoc
xml = '''
<AppTestData>
    <Contact>
        <Name>
         <First_name> foo</First_name>
         <last_name> bar</last_name>
        </Name>
        <Age>33</Age>
        <City>York</City>
        ...
    </Contact>
    <Agent>
        <Code>A103S</Code>
        <Region>North</Region>
        <Resp>Service</Resp>
        ....
    </Agent>
    <Product>
        <Cat>Electronics</Cat>
        ...
    </Product> 
</AppTestData>
'''

def printTag(lst, parent):
    if len(lst)==1:
        parent.append(lst[0].tag)
        print (parent)
        return

    flag = False
    for ele in lst:
        children = ele.children
        if not children:
            flag = True
        else:
            p = parent[:]
            p.append(ele.tag)
            printTag(children,p)
    if flag:
        parent.append(lst.tag)
        print (parent)

# xml = utils.getFileContent('data.xml')
doc  = SimplifiedDoc(xml)
root  = doc.child
children = root.children
printTag(children,[root.tag])
```

Result:

```
['AppTestData', 'Contact', 'Name', ['First_name', 'last_name']]
['AppTestData', 'Contact', ['Name', 'Age', 'City']]
['AppTestData', 'Agent', ['Code', 'Region', 'Resp']]
['AppTestData', 'Product', 'Cat']
```